# Windows XP won't boot correctly after installing Guild Wars

Tags: windows-xp, boot

Yesterday I decided I'd install Guild Wars once again, as I haven't played it for a long time. When I finally completed the installation, and wanted to enter a city, it told me I had to download 9000 files (it did this automatically), and this took a long time. Because I didn't want this to happen every time I enter a city, I searched for a solution, and found out I could place "-image" behind the target of the shortcut to download all files at once. It turned out I had to download 119000 files, but I was about to go to bed, so it could do that over night.

I woke up this morning to find out it had completed the download completely. I removed "-image" from the shortcut's target and rebooted the PC, as most installations work best after a reboot, and my PC had been on all night anyway.

I saw the Windows XP booting screen, because of something I was too lazy to fix I even ran a [CHKDSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK) immediately after the booting screen, and finally, after it did this without any errors, I got a black screen. The monitor gives me an orange light, like it does when it goes stand-by. So I wait. It doesn't seem to work. I reboot my PC, and use 'last working configuration'. It doesn't work either. I reboot it and let it boot normally. I've been waiting for over 10 minutes now, it doesn't sound like my PC is actually doing something, so now I'm worried. It also appears all cables are inserted correctly.

I have rebooted my PC to use a CD-Rom Slax version, and this seems to work correctly.

Right now, I'm busy copying the Guild Wars files to my USB-stick, after which I'll delete them from my Hard Drive. If this doesn't seem to fix the problem, I can just replace them and search for another possible solution.

Comment: Are you able to boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. (Sorry to reply so late)

Comment: New topic/question about internet connection:
http://superuser.com/questions/371270/no-internet-connection

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that guildwars installed some "broken" or unsupported video driver that was activated after the reboot. So your PC may be booting correctly except for the fact that the video is "off".

Try reinstalling video drivers in safe mode.